# In a collision between two masses equal in all measures but with one at 0.5C and the other at .005C, what is the relative damage to each?

Tags: special-relativity, collision

Given that mass increases with velocity approaching infinity at the speed of light $c$, would a collision between 2 equal masses with one travelling at $0.5c$ colliding with its equal travelling at $0.005c$ result in greater damage to the slower mass as the first would possess much higher kinetic energy?

Comment: *mass increases with velocity* Relativistic mass is an obsolete, confusing, and unnecessary concept. It is no longer used in modern physics.

Comment: In another, equally valid reference frame, the two masses are traveling with the same speed.  So why would you expect one to be more damaged than the other?

Answer (score 4):

In the centre of mass frame, the two objects would have the same momenta (but in opposite directions) and, since they have the same mass, the same velocities (again, in opposite directions). Therefore, by symmetry, they would both be affected the same by the collision.

Comment: Perhaps I failed to make the question clear.  The two objects when at the same velocity are identical including mass.  Then when one is accelerated to 100 times the velocity of the other and they are collided together, would not the object of higher velocity now have higher mass as per its higher energy state per E=MC2, and thus exert greater damage to the slower object?

Comment: @DavidJudge As G. Smith pointed out above, relativistic mass is an outdated concept and is not really useful. Also, since special relativity postulates that the laws of physics are the same in all inertial reference frames, there is no absolute way to say the one of the objects in question is moving faster than the other. Each object sees itself as stationary with the other moving toward it.

Comment: Having reviewed the answers and comments and read relevant text, I understand the reasoning.  Thanks to those providing commentary and answers.

Comment: @DavidJudge If you think this has answered your question, you can click the green checkmark to mark it as "accepted."